# check variables and group them according to group belonging

Tags: r

I want to check variables and group them according to which group they belong. If they belong to both groups, it gets marked with `"X"`.

```
grp1 <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
grp2 <- c("F","G","H","I","J","K")
DF <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,3,3), dis = c("A","B","H","B","K"))
DF
  id dis
1  1   A
2  1   B
3  2   H
4  3   B
5  3   K
```

And the result should look like this:

```
  id dis grp
1  1   A   1
2  1   B   1
3  2   H   2
4  3   B   X
5  3   K   X
```

Any good ideas?

Comment: `grp2` should include `K`, right?

Comment: Yes of course. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution

```r
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  mutate(grps = case_when(
    dis %in% grp1 ~ 1,
    dis %in% grp2  ~ 2)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(temp = mean(grps)) %>%
  mutate(grp = case_when(
    temp == 1 ~ "1",
    temp == 2 ~ "2",
    temp == 1.5 ~ "X")
  ) %>%
  select(-grps,-temp)

 #> # A tibble: 5 x 3
 #> # Groups:   id [3]
 #>      id dis   grp  
 #>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 #> 1     1 A     1    
 #> 2     1 B     1    
 #> 3     2 H     2    
 #> 4     3 B     X    
 #> 5     3 K     X
```

Comment: Like this dplyr solution, thanks. Let´s say I have 4 groups and I would like to label all combinations. (Fx. grp1+grp2;  grp1+grp3; grp1+grp4.....etc) Hard to use mean in that case? Best /H

Comment: True, I noticed most of the answers not just mine went the mathematical route.  It extends to any number of groups but not interaction.  Might be simpler at some point to `DF %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     summarise(groups=paste(dis, collapse=""))` then just case_when all the rules

Answer (score 3):

Another base R option via `ave`

```
within(DF, grp <- ave(dis, id, FUN = function(x) {
  if (all(x %in% grp1)) {
    "1"
  } else if (all(x %in% grp2)) {
    "2"
  } else {
    "x"
  }
}))
```

which gives

```
  id dis grp
1  1   A   1
2  1   B   1
3  2   H   2
4  3   B   x
5  3   K   x
```

Comment: It's more concise than mine! I'm stuck here for a long time...

Answer (score 1):

A `base` solution with `merge()` and `ave()`

```
DF2 <- setNames(stack(list(`1` = grp1, `2` = grp2)), c("dis", "grp"))
DF3 <- merge(DF, DF2, all.x = T)
DF3 <- within(DF3[order(DF3$id), ], grp <- ave(as.character(grp), id,
  FUN = function(x) if(length(unique(x)) == 1) x[1] else "X"))

DF3

#   dis id grp
# 1   A  1   1
# 2   B  1   1
# 4   H  2   2
# 3   B  3   X
# 5   K  3   X
```